# Picking up the date from very long string name column in Sybase

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I am working in Sybase with these this table having column 'ID', 'File_Name'

Table1

```
IDS    File_Name_Attached
123    ROSE1234_abcdefghi_03012014_04292014_190038.zip   
456    ROSE1234_abcdefghi_08012014_04292014_190038.zip
```

All I need is to pickup the first date given in file name.

Required:

```
IDS     Dates  
123    03012014
456    08012014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING` and `PATINDEX` to find start_index of date:

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376798)**

```
CREATE TABLE #table1(IDS int, File_Name_attached NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #table1
VALUES (123, 'ROSE1234_abcdefghi_03012014_04292014_190038.zip'),
(456, 'ROSE1234_abcdefghi_08012014_04292014_190038.zip');

SELECT
  IDS,
  [DATES] = SUBSTRING(File_Name_attached,
                      PATINDEX('%_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_%', File_Name_attached) + 1,
                      8)
FROM #table1;
```

*Warning*

I have no Sybase DB for testing so if this won't work let me know.

Comment: Its coming as plan text how to convert into regular date formate MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @Qasim0787 `DECLARE @D NVARCHAR(100) = '03012014';

SELECT cast(right(@D, 4)+substring(@D, 3, 2)+left(@D, 2) as datetime);`